# How to run all migrations in reverse in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to run `rake db:migrate:down` on all of my migrations in rails 3.1. Some other questions suggest doing `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=0`, but that gives me this error:

```
No migration with version number 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rake db:migrate VERSION=0`